# Using CSS, how can i target a content which has a class applied on its parent tag?

Tags: css

I want to remove the word CART and the link applied to it. How can i target it via CSS

```html
<div class="header-contact">
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <a href="tel:18338696433"><b> +(1)-833-869-6433 </b></a>
  <span class="gap">|</span>
  <a href="#">CART</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to hide the link:

```css
.header-contact .gap + a { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="header-contact">
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <a href="tel:18338696433"><b> +(1)-833-869-6433 </b></a>
  <span class="gap">|</span>
  <a href="#">CART</a>
</div>
```

If you also want to hide the divider `.gap`:

```css
.header-contact [href^=tel] ~ * { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="header-contact">
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <a href="tel:18338696433"><b> +(1)-833-869-6433 </b></a>
  <span class="gap">|</span>
  <a href="#">CART</a>
</div>
```

Comment: In StackOverflow, when your question is answered, you click the checkmark left of the answer that suits best so others see a) **that** your question has an answer already and b) others see **which** answer actually solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try `.header-contact a:nth-of-type(2) { display: none;}` if the structure stays always the same.